# CSV export has different values to SQL output

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

In phpmyadmin in a mariadb install, I have a SQL statement

```
SELECT `datepaid`, SUM(`total`) FROM `tblinvoices` WHERE `status` = "paid" AND `total` > 0 GROUP BY YEAR(datepaid)*100 + MONTH(datepaid) ORDER BY `datepaid` ASC
```

The output is as expected, I get a list of totals grouped by month, ordered by month. The last 5 rows look like this:

```
2020-06-09 13:01:31    4485.56
2020-07-07 12:36:25    4519.69
2020-08-03 13:02:29    3685.26
2020-09-26 05:49:25    4371.98
2020-10-10 16:47:32    5135.75
```

At the bottom of the list of all rows, I check all, then click export (under the results, not in the top menu).

In the resulting CSV the last 5 rows are

```
"2020-06-09 13:01:31","29.00"
"2020-07-07 12:36:25","130.50"
"2020-08-03 13:02:29","99.00"
"2020-09-26 05:49:25","385.00"
"2020-10-10 16:47:32","46.20"
```

It looks like the output has included one of the rows in the group, rather than the group total.

Am I doing something wrong (most likely) or is this some sort of bug?

**[UPDATE]**

Based on the info from @nbk I found a solution and learned something, the INTO command

```
`INSERT INTO `another_table` SELECT `datepaid`, SUM(`total`) FROM `tblinvoices` WHERE `status` = "paid" AND `total` > 0 GROUP BY YEAR(datepaid)*100 + MONTH(datepaid) ORDER BY `datepaid` ASC
```

Comment: You should GROUP BY and SELECT datepaid the same way.

Comment: why nozt use INTO outfile?

Comment: @jarlh can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: You GROUP BY values like 202010, but SELECT values like 2020-10-10 16:47:32. What do you expect to be returned if October 2020 has several, different datepaid values?

Comment: the point is here, that the columns are not  summed up when exporting with phpmyadmin

Comment: @nbk your INTO solution has worked for me.  If you make it an answer I will accept.

Comment: @jarlh thanks, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INTO OUTFILE`

Like

```
SELECT 
    `datepaid`, SUM(`total`)
FROM
    `tblinvoices`
WHERE
    `status` = 'paid' AND `total` > 0
GROUP BY YEAR(datepaid) * 100 + MONTH(datepaid)
ORDER BY `datepaid` ASC

INTO OUTFILE 'C:/tmp/cancelled_orders.csv' 
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TERMINATED BY ';' 
ESCAPED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Depending onb the system configuration, you must check the flder

Comment: I actually ended up going INTO a table as there was a permissions error on the server, but the concept works.  Thanks